# Is there any dependency file for python project. Like composer.json or package.json?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, composer-php, libraries

I want to know is there a package dependences file for a python project like there is composer.json and package.json. I just have to run a command to install all dependences. I have installed all my python libraries by using pip. So please help me in this.

Comment: You should take a look to pip, easy_install or conda. For conda: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-you-need-python-environments-and-how-to-manage-them-with-conda-85f155f4353c/